# parse values from javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I see there is a problem to get a String name from JSON object's name.
I need to parse this kind on JSON response from server.

```
var response = {
  hopaopGmailsjIpW: {
    GmailsjIpW_totalEmails_count: 133,
    GmailsjIpW_state: 1
  },
  hopaopGmail4y4yu: {
    Gmail4y4yu_totalEmails_count: 156,
    Gmail4y4yu_state: 1
  }
}
```

It is not an `Array`, but the object with inner objects.
i need to parse an inner ojects name and add additional values to each object.

i want be able **to do something like this:**

```
for(var i =0; i < response.length; i++){
  response[i].username = parseUsernameFromString(response[i]);
  response[i].service = parseServiceFromString(response[i]);
  response[i].id = parseIdString(response[i]);
}
```

(and also state for each task)

So the question is:
**What is the best way to make it?**

**UPDATE**
this is exactly what i have for now:

```
for(var key in response){
    if(stringContains(response[key], "Gmail")) { response[key].service = "Gmail";}
        console.log("task name: "+ response[key].service);
}
function stringContains(originalString, searchString){
        if(originalString.indexOf(searchString) > -1){
            return true
        }
            else return false;
}
```

Comment: Your first block of code is not JSON, nor is it JavaScript. You'd need to write a custom parser for it (start reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)). It would be better to fix the server so the response is actually JSON.

Comment: The thing is it is a request from some implementation of dataCache on server side, changing server part is too much work, doesn't worth. also i have this situation only in one place in my app.

Comment: right, comma is missing, sorry,

Comment: Are you asking how to loop through the object, or how to write the `parseUsernameFromString` etc functions? The question isn't very clear.

Comment: That structure is just truly, truly bizarre. It really needs fixing. The properties of the inner objects should have consistent names, for one. Basic principles, people.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agree with this.

Comment: 'i need to parse an inner ojects name and add additional values to each object.'

whats what i asking.

The structure of objects is like this because it is an object drom datacache in back end which is working with multithreaded async tasks and each group, user, task need to have their id's.. anyway thats not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For walking through Objects, you need to use `for ... in` loop.

The **real problem** is: There's a `,` missing in your code. See the fixed working snippet:

**Snippet**

```js
var response_Parsed = {
  hopaopGmailsjIpW: {
    GmailsjIpW_totalEmails_count: 133,
    GmailsjIpW_state: 1,
    service: 'Gmail',
    username: 'hopaop',
    id: 'sjIpW'
  },
  hopaopGmail4y4yu: {
    Gmail4y4yu_totalEmails_count: 156,
    Gmail4y4yu_state: 1,
    service: 'Gmail',
    username: 'hopaop',
    id: '4y4yu'
  }
};
for (id in response_Parsed) {
  console.log("----");
  if (id.indexOf("Gmail") > -1) {
    console.log("We have Gmail: " + id);
    console.log("UniqueName:    " + id.replace("hopaopGmail", ""));
    console.log("Username:      " + response_Parsed[id].username);
    console.log("Email Count:   " + response_Parsed[id][id.replace("hopaop", "") + "_totalEmails_count"]);
  }
  else
    console.log("We don't have Gmail: " + id);
}
```

And also the right way to enumerate the through the keys of the objects, is by using `Object.keys`.

Comment: Is there anything else I should add or correct to make this answer a better one?

Comment: i can't know the exact values of `hopaopGmail4y4yu` for example because it include generic ID. Yes, comma was missing.

Comment: sorry, but this is not the answer.

Comment: @user1935987 Now you can. Did you check my snippet, it shows you in the console as well. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: `console.log(response[id].GmailsjIpW_totalEmails_count);`
i can't do make there because i don't know if there `GmailsjIpW_totalEmails_count`

Comment: @user1935987 You wanna get the count right, updating.

Comment: i don't need the count, i need to parse object's name

Comment: ex:
` hopaopGmail4y4yu` 
`username: hopaop`
`service: gmail`
`id: 4y4yu`

Comment: @user1935987 Check now

Comment: @user1935987 You are looking for: `console.log(response[id][id.replace("hopaop", "") + "_totalEmails_count"]);`

Comment: @user1935987: You just have to apply what Praveen showed you not just to the outermost object (as he has), but then *also* to the objects its properties refer to. It's just applying the same principle.

Comment: @user1935987 Are you convinced or still not yet?

Comment: i can't operate with `hopaopGmailsjIpW` as with string. isn't it?

Comment: @user1935987 Did you see the solution I posted? The comment I made a few seconds ago?

Comment: because it's what i had before this question:
`
            for (var element in key){
                if(stringContains(element, "Gmail")) {console.log("Key contains string Gmail");}
            }
`

and i get errors because `string.indexOf()` don't work on the key

Comment: @user1935987 You are making no sense. I don't understand what exactly you are expecting.

Comment: just give me some time

Comment: @user1935987 Still didn't understand what you are expecting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Does anything make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115509/discussion-between-user1935987-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: the problem was that i was parsing `response[key]` , but not the `key`

Answer (score 1):

If the response is a String like you wrote, you should first parse the JSON-String into an Object (if you're using a library like jQuery, it's probably already a JSON, as this conversion is done by jQuery automatically):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(responseString);
```

Afterwards you may iterate through it like posted above:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log("key", key, "value", obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: *Afterwards you may iterate through it like posted above* What's your answer good for then? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, my answer was some second later, so i added this sentence. Still it contains the JSON.parse part.

Comment: @MattDiMu I was more interested on you removing that JSON Object. There's nothing like that. How do you say, "JavaScript Object Notation Object"? `:D`